# NodeJs: run my app in webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new at nodejs so i dont really know how to make this work.

I have code which creates json output when i run `node app.js` from my console.

now i want to have the same json output in my website

so if someone enter `example.com:8000` it will run the `node app.js`

My code is:

```
'use strict';

var pa11y = require();

// Create a test instance with some default options
var test = pa11y({

    // Log what's happening to the console
    log: {
        debug: console.log.bind(console),
        error: console.error.bind(console),
        info: console.log.bind(console)
    }

});

test.run('example.com', function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error.message);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

**UPDATE:**
i have tried to use `expressjs`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello world!");
    test.run('example.com', function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error.message);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
});
```

"Hello word" is working fine.

and all what i have tried to print the output from the  `test.run('example.com', function(error, result) {` without any success.

what i need to do to make this work with `expressjs`

Comment: I will prefer you take [Express tutorials by Tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/), then resolve your issue.

Comment: @cdaiga HI, that's what i have tried but did not work. i have added an update to my question. can you look what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to study (express)[http://expressjs.com/] or (koa)[http://koajs.com/] frame commbine with (nodejs API)[https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/],it's easy to study,helpful to understand.